# Prove that the expectation value of $E[(\min(X,Y)^2] < \infty$ is well-defined.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Say that we have two non-negative random variables $X, Y$ that independent and identically distributed over the same sample spaces $\Omega$. We know that the expectation of $X$ are well-defined well the one of $X^2$ not. what I wanna know is wether

$$
\mathbb{E}[\max(X,Y)^2]
$$

and

$$
\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)^2]
$$

is also well-defined or not?

Comment: Do you have any arguments pro or con of yours?

Comment: I would try to calculate the probability density function for min(X,Y) first and then calculate the term asked in the question, but didn’t go further ...